# Is it possible to add apps to spaces with the GraphQL API reference?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I try to create a new space and add members and apps to the created space. But I can only find information how to add members to a space and it's not mentioned how to add apps to a space.

Create Space API reference: https://developer.watsonwork.ibm.com/docs/space/create-a-space

When I list the space details all apps are in the member list by I cannot add them as a member.

Manual add app to Space:

https://help.workspace.ibm.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012694447-Adding-apps-to-your-space

Answer (score 0):

The following information was provided by Watson Workspace Support:

The available apps to add are in the apps view of space settings. Each space maintains its own members and its own apps (two different views under space settings). Any app that you have created will be available and show up in the apps view as well as a few apps that have been preapproved. If you have an essentials account or are using essentials, you can have further administration ability as a space owner to restrict people from adding apps to your space. Thus, that capability would need to be set to allow the problem user to be able to adds apps.

Hopefully this information helps. If not, post more information and I will convey it to the team. They would need some more details and accompanying screenshots.